# Landscape + navigation drawer animation + new activity = bug?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Here's what's happening.. from my navigation drawer I select an item that then starts up a new activity. Now the thing is I want to close the navigation drawer before opening the new activity, but I don't want the delay to be too long so what I do is start the new activity with a postdelayed handler of about 200ms after a call to closeDrawer(). SO, the drawer is still closing when the new activity gets initialized. The problem kicks in when I go back to the original activity: the layout is shifted about halfway up the screen and tiled in a weird way. Doesn't seem to get fixed until you interact with it (so I'm assuming it gets fixed with the onDraw() call).

Conditions that make this crop up:

- Device is in LANDSCAPE mode (doesn't happen on portrait)
- The navigation drawer is animating out of view when startActivity() is called

Any insight? Bonus question: is there an easy way of making the navigation drawer close without the animation?

EDIT: Turns out the same thing happens if I'm in landscape and use startActivityForResult(). It's not an issue with only startActivity() though..

Answer (score 0):

In your onAuthenticatedResume() of DrawerActivity, try configuring the DrawerManager & Toggle for drawer properly. The code looks like the snippet below ( I just added some dummy lines like 'YourDrawerManager' means whatever the manager you have )

```
@Override
    protected void onAuthenticatedResume() {
        super.onAuthenticatedResume();
            //Configure NavigationDrawer
            navigationDrawerManager = new YourDrawerManager();
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.your_layout);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.logo, "OK",
                "Close") {

            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(your_title_string));
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go! Have a read at my edit though, I think I might've partially misdiagnosed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out what the issue was.

The problem was that in my AndroidManifest.xml I declared the new activities as having screenOrientation="portrait" and only enabled orientation changes in the onCreate method for them if certain conditions were met.

I'm still not 100% clear on what was happening but it seems that the device would try to rotate to portrait on activity change, then go back to landscape before drawing the new activity (since it was enabled in onCreate) and then that somehow messed up the previous activity so that when I went back to it, it would get shifted weirdly.

Still an Android bug IMO, but at least I know what it stems from now.

Changed screenOrientation to "landscape" and it works fine now (this problem doesn't arise when the first activity is in portrait and the second is locked to landscape in the manifest... what???)